# not able to write each in function class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am not able to write   each function class
whenever i write following things , it's give me error why?

```
<script>
        var addLi = function($li) {
            var $uls = $('ul');
            $.each($uls, function(index, ul) {
                // If this ul has less than 5 li's
                // then add the li here
                if ($(this).find('li').length < 5) {
                    $(this).append($li);
                    // exit the for loop since we have placed this li
                    return;  
                }
            }
            };
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: The screenshot already shows you why: `Expected ')'`. The parsers expects a `)` there. What is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply did not close the `.each()` command.

```
$.each($uls, function(index, ul) {
  // If this ul has less than 5 li's
  // then add the li here
  if ($(this).find('li').length < 5) {
    $(this).append($li);
    // exit the for loop since we have placed this li
    return;  
  }
}); // <---------- here is the closing brackets for the each()
```

The callback function for the each is terminated by the curly brackets but it is only a parameter for the `each()` command.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
    var addLi = function($li) {
        var $uls = $('ul');
        $.each($uls, function(index, ul) {
            // If this ul has less than 5 li's
            // then add the li here
            if ($(this).find('li').length < 5) {
                $(this).append($li);
                // exit the for loop since we have placed this li
                return;  
            }
        }); // close brace missing here before
    };
</script>
```

You missed `);` for `$.each`